# Capture Group Regex Qradar

Tags: regex, capture-group

I did somme parsing for example :

1. `',+([A-Za-zA-zÀ-ú+ \/\w+0-9._%+-]+(?=,))'`
2. `'---=+([A-Za-zÀ-ú+ \/\w+0-9._%+-]+(?=&))'`

and i must enter a capture group in QRadar, the both match logs correctly, but the first one accept this capture group $1, and the second one doesn't accept it, it accept only 1 in the capture group, what can i do for enter this capture group $1 in the second one

Comment: See the green-highlighed text [here](https://regex101.com/r/VtgKc5/1), is it what you need? Then all you need is to use `$1` to reference the Group 1 text in QRadar.

Comment: yes i need this green highlighted and it matched correctly in QRadar. the problem why is accept $1 just for the first regex and it doesn't accept it for the second one despite it match the  field correctly?

Comment: Maybe the second regex just does not match the text? What are you trying to match? Please share the input text.

Comment: ---=AAA&
,AAA,  
this is example of logs , and the both of regex match correctly  the field wanted, but qradar accept $1 for the first regex but doesn't accept $1 for the second

Comment: Maybe it is the problem with configuration: the first regex matches the string and the next one does not process the already matched one. Sorry, it is no longer a regex, but a QRadar problem, and sounds off-topic here since it is not a programming thing.

Comment: I see thank's for u're Replay